# How to restrict keys of Typescript index signatures

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, index-signature

I have an object literal that maps key-value pairs. Is it possible to restrict the index signature key to a range of **pre-defined** values?

I tried the following but no error gets thrown when using the unspecified key "c":

```
let foo: { [key in 'a' | 'b']: any };

foo['c']; // no error
```

**Updated:**

The example above **will** throw an error when using "noImplicitAny" (see comments below).

In my code I'm actually using a variable instead of a hard coded value, so (I guess) Typescript can't know in advance if given value is allowed or not:

```
let foo: { [key in 'a' | 'b']: any };

foo[someDynamicKey]; // no error
```

Comment: Are you really accessing `foo` like `foo['c']`? Or is it really `foo[someVar]` where `someVar` comes from outside your code and could be any string? (If the former, why not `foo.c`, which would work [e.g., cause an error] with the type `{ a: any, b: any }`?) (If the latter, I don't think TypeScript can help, but I've been wrong about that before... :-) )

Comment: The way you're assigning using bracket notation won't ever throw an error

Comment: This will throw an error if you have `noImplictAny` turned on

Comment: @CertainPerformance `[]` is checked and will give errors with `noImplictAny`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - You have an amazingly consistent typo when you type that flag name. :-) Twice here, once in the linked question's answer...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah for some reason my fingers refuse to write that one right, I'll correct it in the answer, 10x :) (Oh you beat me to it, double thank you :)

Comment: I'm actually passing in a variable that contains the key, so I guess Typescript can't help me here since the value is determined at runtime. "noImplicitAny" works for the code example above tough, thanks!

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - The OP has updated the question. I suspect TypeScript can't help, but as I say above, I've been wrong before... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If `let someDynamicKey: string;` then under `noImplicitAny` ts will not let you use it as an index to `foo` so you will still get an error.. If the `let someDynamicKey: 'a' | 'b';` then the access is valid as far as TS is concerned..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Yeah, the key thing in my comment above is "...from outside your code..." (e.g., if all the OP knows at compile-time is `string`). He/she didn't actually say that above, but I suspect that's the case.